# How use FULLTEXT SEARCH in mysql without special tags(<html>,<p> and other)

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I make sarch in mysql with help next code:

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('database');
```

How use search in mysql without special tags(`<html>`,`<p>` and other)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a php function can do this

```
strip_tags($text);
```

You can find more information here 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

If you still want to do this in mysql , you have to define your own function

```
delimiter ||
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS strip_tags||
CREATE FUNCTION strip_tags( x longtext) RETURNS longtext
LANGUAGE SQL NOT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE sstart INT UNSIGNED;
DECLARE ends INT UNSIGNED;
SET sstart = LOCATE('<', x, 1);
REPEAT
SET ends = LOCATE('>', x, sstart);
SET x = CONCAT(SUBSTRING( x, 1 ,sstart -1) ,SUBSTRING(x, ends +1 )) ;
SET sstart = LOCATE('<', x, 1);
UNTIL sstart < 1 END REPEAT;
return x;
END;
||
delimiter ;
```

Call the function in your search query after you define the function

```
$q="CALL strip_tags(SELECT textarea FROM table where ....)"
```

Comment: oh.. can you said about use "strip_tags(SELECT textarea FROM table where ....)"  $res=mysql_query(strip_tags("SELECT textarea FROM table where ....")) or how?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the HTML tags before you store text in the column which is FULLTEXT indexed. If you need the original text, store that in a different column.

Alternatively, use a real search indexer, like Lucene. MySQL FULLTEXT is kind of a toy.

Comment: im need sql search with php code. and can i exclude from my search tags?

Comment: We will not write your code for you. (Not that we even *could*, since we don't know what your application looks like.)

Comment: it's usually mysql tables with sql query

Comment: I have data stored with tags, and tags must be excluded from the search